# navbar-toggle button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using Bootsrap and I'm having difficulty getting the navbar-toggle button to work.

At first I thought it was something with my navbar code, so I pasted in the example on the [Bootstrap Website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) although that didn't work either. The button shows, although not the dropdown when you click on it.

When I search through my files for the project, I see collapse.js within bootstrap/js/collapse.js.

I'm using Angular as well.Here is my code for my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top top-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="{{side.landingState}}">
        <img class="logo" alt="Logo" src="/assets/img/side_logo_red.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="main-menu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-list {{side.role}}" data-ng-if="!Guest">
        <li class="active nav-icon"><a ui-sref="{{side.homeState}}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
        <li class="active nav-icon"><a ui-sref="{{side.postsState}}" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"></a></li>
        <li class="active nav-icon" data-ng-if="Student"><a ui-sref="{{side.profilePage}}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown active nav-icon">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
            <li data-ng-if="User"><a role="menuitem" ui-sref="{{side.settingsState}}"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></div><div class="text">Settings</div></a></li>
            <li><a role="menuitem" ui-sref="{{side.futureState}}"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></div><div class="text">Future Services</div></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider" data-ng-if="user"></li>
            <li data-ng-if="user"><a role="menuitem" data-ng-click="logout()"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></div><div class="text">Logout</div></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav-list {{side.role}}" data-ng-if="guest">
        <li class="nav-icon"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Sign Up</li>
        <li class="nav-icon">Stuff...</li>
        <li class="nav-icon">More Stuff...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Update:**

I ended up just using data-ng-class to toggle the collapse class based on a variable that the button set.

`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-ng-click="toggleCollapsed()">`

And then in the controller I used

`$scope.collapsed = true;
 $scope.toggleCollapsed = function(){
  $scope.collapsed = !$scope.collapsed;
 };`

Comment: Is bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js being called by the document?

Comment: ^ that. just ran this in jsfiddle and seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/s1p9fa0t/

Comment: I believe? This is in the index.html file: `<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

you need to have these both:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

and make sure you are not getting any errors in the console.

and if you are trying to execute from the phone, you need to add this to your index.html:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

Comment: I tried adding those to my index.html, although it still doesn't work. I'm not sure what else could be the problem. Is there anything that would override those classes? Or is there some container class that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please check your console and let me know if you see any errors?